# Paypal coupon Code checkout

Tags: php, jquery, paypal

I am trying to making simple product checkout system for my site. I am using paypal default checkout system. It is working fine but I need coupon code facility also. I never see any options in paypal for coupon code thing. That’s why I tried to create that via jquery.

I successful made that but it is work only on one product.  When I add more product in page this it is not work.  I can understand it about class and id issue but still I don’t figure out how to do that. also trying for discount as `%` wise  current my code only work hard coded price.

Would you guys check my code see where my mistake is or how can make it.  Or if there have any other way to do

**HTML**

```
<h2>  Product 1 - $4.99</h2> 
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="paypal" class="frm_paypal">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="info@soming.com" />
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Chile Powder" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="0001" />
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" class="amount" value="4.99" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
    <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products" />
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="tax_rate" value="0.082" />
    <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF:btn_cart_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest" />
    <input type="image" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" name="submit" src="http://oldstoberfest.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/buynow.png" class="btnPaypal" />
    <div class="div_coupon_code">
        <div class="div_msg"></div>If you have any coupon code please enter Otherwise leave it blank and Press checkout.
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="coupon_code" value="" placeholder="Coupon Code" />
        <br>
        <input type="button" class="btnCheckOut" name="btnCheckOut" value="Checkout" /> <span class="span_pay">
        <input type="button" class="btnPay" name="btnPay" value="Pay" />
        </span> 
    </div>
    <img alt="" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0" />
</form>
 <h2>  Product 2 - $6.99</h2> 
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="paypal" class="frm_paypal">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="info@soming.com" />
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Chile Powder" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="0002" />
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" class="amount" value="6.99" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
    <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products" />
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="tax_rate" value="0.082" />
    <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF:btn_cart_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest" />
    <input type="image" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" name="submit" src="http://oldstoberfest.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/buynow.png" class="btnPaypal" />
    <div class="div_coupon_code">
        <div class="div_msg"></div>If you have any coupon code please enter Otherwise leave it blank and Press checkout.
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="coupon_code" value="" placeholder="Coupon Code" />
        <br>
        <input type="button" class="btnCheckOut" name="btnCheckOut" value="Checkout" /> <span class="span_pay">
        <input type="button" class="btnPay" name="btnPay" value="Pay" />
        </span> 
    </div>
    <img alt="" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0" />
</form>

<h2>  Product 3 - $8.99</h2> 
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="paypal" class="frm_paypal">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="info@soming.com" />
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Chile Powder" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="0003" />
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" class="amount" value="8.99" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
    <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products" />
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="tax_rate" value="0.082" />
    <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF:btn_cart_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest" />
    <input type="image" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" name="submit" src="http://oldstoberfest.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/buynow.png" class="btnPaypal" />
    <div class="div_coupon_code">
        <div class="div_msg"></div>If you have any coupon code please enter Otherwise leave it blank and Press checkout.
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="coupon_code" value="" placeholder="Coupon Code" />
        <br>
        <input type="button" class="btnCheckOut" name="btnCheckOut" value="Checkout" /> <span class="span_pay">
        <input type="button" class="btnPay" name="btnPay" value="Pay" />
        </span> 
    </div>
    <img alt="" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0" />
</form>
 <h2>  Product 4 - $1.99</h2> 
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="paypal" class="frm_paypal">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="info@soming.com" />
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Chile Powder" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="0004" />
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" class="amount" value="1.99" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
    <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products" />
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="tax_rate" value="0.082" />
    <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF:btn_cart_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest" />
    <input type="image" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" name="submit" src="http://oldstoberfest.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/buynow.png" class="btnPaypal" />
    <div class="div_coupon_code">
        <div class="div_msg"></div>If you have any coupon code please enter Otherwise leave it blank and Press checkout.
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="coupon_code" value="" placeholder="Coupon Code" />
        <br>
        <input type="button" class="btnCheckOut" name="btnCheckOut" value="Checkout" /> <span class="span_pay">
        <input type="button" class="btnPay" name="btnPay" value="Pay" />
        </span> 
    </div>
    <img alt="" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0" />
</form>
 <h2>  Product 5 - $6.99</h2> 
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="paypal" class="frm_paypal">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="info@soming.com" />
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Chile Powder" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="0005" />
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" class="amount" value="6.99" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
    <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products" />
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="tax_rate" value="0.082" />
    <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF:btn_cart_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest" />
    <input type="image" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" name="submit" src="http://oldstoberfest.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/buynow.png" class="btnPaypal" />
    <div class="div_coupon_code">
        <div class="div_msg"></div>If you have any coupon code please enter Otherwise leave it blank and Press checkout.
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="coupon_code" value="" placeholder="Coupon Code" />
        <br>
        <input type="button" class="btnCheckOut" name="btnCheckOut" value="Checkout" /> <span class="span_pay">
        <input type="button" class="btnPay" name="btnPay" value="Pay" />
        </span> 
    </div>
    <img alt="" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0" />
</form>

<h2>  Product 6 - $6.99</h2> 
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="paypal" class="frm_paypal">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="info@soming.com" />
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Chile Powder" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="0006" />
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" class="amount" value="6.99" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
    <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products" />
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="tax_rate" value="0.082" />
    <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF:btn_cart_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest" />
    <input type="image" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" name="submit" src="http://oldstoberfest.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/buynow.png" class="btnPaypal" />
    <div class="div_coupon_code">
        <div class="div_msg"></div>If you have any coupon code please enter Otherwise leave it blank and Press checkout.
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="coupon_code" value="" placeholder="Coupon Code" />
        <br>
        <input type="button" class="btnCheckOut" name="btnCheckOut" value="Checkout" /> <span class="span_pay">
        <input type="button" class="btnPay" name="btnPay" value="Pay" />
        </span> 
    </div>
    <img alt="" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0" />
</form>
 <h2>  Product 7 - $6.99</h2> 
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="paypal" class="frm_paypal">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="info@soming.com" />
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Chile Powder" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="0007" />
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" class="amount" value="6.99" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
    <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products" />
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="tax_rate" value="0.082" />
    <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF:btn_cart_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest" />
    <input type="image" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" name="submit" src="http://oldstoberfest.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/buynow.png" class="btnPaypal" />
    <div class="div_coupon_code">
        <div class="div_msg"></div>If you have any coupon code please enter Otherwise leave it blank and Press checkout.
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="coupon_code" value="" placeholder="Coupon Code" />
        <br>
        <input type="button" class="btnCheckOut" name="btnCheckOut" value="Checkout" /> <span class="span_pay">
        <input type="button" class="btnPay" name="btnPay" value="Pay" />
        </span> 
    </div>
    <img alt="" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0" />
</form>
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('body').on('click','#btnPaypal', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#div_coupon_code").show("slow");
      return false;
  });

  $('body').on('click','#btnCheckOut', function(e) {
      var coupon=$("#coupon_code").val();
      var go_paypal=1;
      if(coupon=="happy" || coupon=="HAPPY")
      {
        $("#amount").val(5.24);
        $("#div_msg").html("Valid coupon code entered! Click pay to continue").show("slow");
        go_paypal=0;
      }
      else if(coupon!="")
      {
        $("#div_msg").html("Invalid coupon code. Please double check").show("slow");
        go_paypal=1;
      }
      else
        $("#frm_paypal").submit();

      if(go_paypal==0)
      {
        $("#btnCheckOut").hide("slow");
        $("#span_pay").show("fast");
      }
  });

  $('body').on('click','#btnPay', function(e) {
      $("#frm_paypal").submit();
  });
  $("#div_coupon_code").hide();
  $("#span_pay").hide();    
});
```

single product demo
`http://jsfiddle.net/cyber007/gpLeqgzc/`

Multiple product demo
`http://jsfiddle.net/cyber007/3pLv8dy6/`

i will keep update here

Comment: try this : http://jsfiddle.net/3pLv8dy6/1/

Comment: @madalin . thank u so much your trying. i updated html a bit for better understand price . http://jsfiddle.net/cyber007/3pLv8dy6/2/ but i wanted when i put correct coupon code it will reduce 25% price and go checkout. also properly work on multiple product. current for one coupon correct then other also effect

Answer (score 0):

if you want to calculate discount for multiple products dynamically then make sum of all products price and then apply coupon discount after getting total

So,your code should be like this...

```
function calcPrice(){
var v = parseInt(document.getElementById("val").value);
var q = parseInt(document.getElementById("quantity").value);
if ((isNaN(q)) || (q == null) || (q <0)) {
alert ("You must enter a positive number");
document.getElementById("quantity").value = "";
return false;
}
var p = calcTotal(v,q);
alert("Total Price = " + p);
}

function calcTotal(v,q) {
var discount = 0;
if (q>=1) {discount = .25}
var price = q * v;
var savings = price * discount;
var total = price - savings;
return total;
}
```

this is the reference you just need to modify id and class for your HTML